# Find a repeat word in each line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string and I want to find the index of repeated word in each line:

```
string = "string3 is nice, string2 . string3 is good."
x = "string3"
for word in set(string.split()):
 if "string3" in word: 
    u =  string.index(x)
    print(x, u)
```

I want to find "**string3**" and their indexes. The problem in my code it's only finding the first "**string3**" in "`string3 is nice`" and doesn't go to next line `"string3 is good"`

any idea why?..

Comment: you've used a `set(string.split())` which removes all duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `set()` removes duplicates and can change the order (`set`s are unordered in python).

Using `enumerate()` you can get all the indexes for the words:

```
string = "string3 is nice, string2 . string3 is good."
x = "string3"
for u, word in enumerate(string.split()):
   if x == word: 
       print(x, u)
```